# Vuejs npm installation issue in Windows 10

Tags: vue.js, npm-install

I'm trying to install VueJS using npm at my cmd, but it gives me error as shown in the image. How to fix that?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBJ5L.jpg

Comment: are u trying to initialize a vue project?

Comment: Hi, yes! i want to create my first page using vuejs and this will be my first time to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u r trying to create a vue project, u can use vue-cli

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create

`vue create hello-world`

Comment: Thank you! one last question should I run that both on windows cmd or nodejs?

Comment: looks like u hv npm command line globally, u can just run it in cmd

Comment: Alright, thank you so much! I appreciate your help.